# Control MediaElement by custom button in custom MediaTransportControls

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, mediaelement

From this official article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187271.aspx

I know how to create custom button in custom `MediaTransportControls`.
I also know hot to handle button click (also in article).

But I am not sure how to **control mediaElement with my custom button.**

For example I want button, that will set position to 10 seconds.
It is easy in Page, where is `mediaElement` placed:

```
private void myButtonInPageDotXaml(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    mediaElement.Position = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
}
```

How to add this functionality to my custom button in `customMediaTransortControls`?

**Edit:**
I can create public variable in `CustomMediaTransportControls` :

```
public MediaElement me;
```

After that in `MainPage.xaml.cs` do something like this:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        customMTC.me = this.mediaElement;//customMTC is CustomMediTransportControlClass
    }
```

So, I can control `medieElement` from `CustomMediTransportControl` class:

```
private void GoToTenButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         mediaElement.Position = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
    }
```

And it is exactly what I wanted, but I feel this is not the clearest and best solution.

Comment: You solution seems clear enough to me. The only other solution I've found is to write your own transport by scratch.  Which seems overkill for your question.

Answer (score 0):

In the Copy if you defined the Template of MediaTransportControls in "This Document" then, when you edit the Template pick your button go to Event Handlers and create one.

Comment: This is not the problem. I need to control mediElement from CustomMediTransportControl class...

Comment: I do it like i said and it works like a charm never had any problem. I dont think you can override the MediaTransportControls class,. If you dont like to have the code in the MainPage.xaml.cs then create a file like MyMTC.cs and in there continue the partial class of MainPage.